# How to get computer to click on a button

Tags: javascript

The buttons will display a message when they are clicked. When the user click any button,  the computer will automatically trigger  a click Event Listener on another button by clicking it. After the computer click  on a button, a message will be displayed. How do I get the computer to automatically click on button to display the message after user clicked any button? Thank you for your time.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Computer click</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <p id="content2"></p>

    <button id="b1">Click me</button>

    <button id="b2">Click me</button>

    <script>
        let p = document.querySelector("#content");
        let p2 = document.querySelector("#content2");

        let button1= document.querySelector("#b1");
        let button2= document.querySelector("#b2");


        //if this button is clicked, the computer will automatically trigger  a click event on button 2

        button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
            p.textContent = "Hello";

        });


        //if this button is clicked, the computer will automatically trigger  a click event on button 1

        button2.addEventListener("click", function () {
            p2.textContent = "You are great !!!";

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls remove the `if` condition from the code `if (button1.clicked==true)`. This is not needed for calling a click function

Comment: The `if` conditions are preventing the event listeners from being added, but you have nothing in here that will trigger a secondary click event on any other buttons. What do you expect the result to be after the user clicks on one of the buttons?

Comment: document.getElementById("b2").click();

Answer (score -1):

You need remove if conditions,  with `if (button1.clicked==true)`  condition, click event handler did not subscribed.

```js
 let p = document.querySelector("#content");
        let p2 = document.querySelector("#content2");

        let button1= document.querySelector("#b1");
        let button2= document.querySelector("#b2");


        //if this button is clicked, the computer will automatically trigger  a click event on button 2
        
        button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
            p.textContent = "Hello";

        });

    


        //if this button is clicked, the computer will automatically trigger  a click event on button 1
        
        button2.addEventListener("click", function () {
            p2.textContent = "You are great !!!";

        });
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Computer click</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <p id="content2"></p>

    <button id="b1">Click me</button>

    <button id="b2">Click me</button>

  
</body>
</html>
```